Dynamically remove fields of certain type
I have a TypeScript class which is defined as follows:
export interface PickingOrderItem {     
    itemId: string;     
    productId: string;     
    //others 
}


Now at runtime in an Angular environment I enrich these objects with other data like this:
export interface PickingItemWithArticle extends PickingOrderItem{      
    article: Article; 
}

The challenge now is that I need to clean these runtime data before sending the payload to the backend as the additional fields are not existing in API definition. I'm now searching a way to clean those data in a dynamic and generic fashion. I want to be safe that if the Type of PickingItemWithArticle is being extended later on, that the delete is still complete.
Maybe something like this here:
  removeDataOfType<TARGET, INPUT extends TARGET>(pickingOrderItemToSave: INPUT): TARGET {
    const typesToRemove = ['article'];//ToDo: extract types by finding out the delta of types between TARGET and INPUT. All fields that are not part of TARGET must be removed

    const allKeys = Object.keys(pickingOrderItemToSave);
    const deltaKeys = ??// how to get the keys of TARGET??
    const cleanedPickingOrderItemToSave: TARGET = {...pickingOrderItemToSave} as TARGET;
    typesToRemove.forEach(key => delete pickingOrderItemToSave[key]);
    return cleanedPickingOrderItemToSave as TARGET;
  }

I want to call that function like this:
const itemWithArticle: PickingItemWithArticle = {} as PickingItemWithArticle;

const cleanedArticle:PickingOrderItem = removeDataOfType<PickingOrderItem>(itemWithArticle);


I know that the types are removed later through transpiling. So my question is if there is any way to solve this Problem in typscript without fixating the keys to remove?
const allKeys = Object.keys(pickingOrderItemToSave);
const deltaKeys = ??// how to get the keys of TARGET??

I also tried different Type-Helper functions, but they all operate on Type-Level and I somehow need to get the keys of the target object without knowing how to instantiate them.

What's an Article? It would be nice if the code here were a [mre] we could use to get started right away.

(see prev comment). You could write a type guard function and then pass it, as shown in this playground link. But this doesn't seem to help with your apparently underlying use case of dealing with the situation when future extra properties are added that the back end doesn't expect. Because unless you keep adding guards for the extra types, then it will slip through. So is this an XY problem? Please [edit] to clarify how your use case is served by your attempted solution.

Thanks for the reply. As far as I understand it, the fields must be specified in the guard function. The problem with that approach is, that if I add an additional field later on, the guard has to be extended as well. I've adapted your playground to show that the newly added field myNewFancyField isn't removed. Is there any chance to have that dynamic and generic?

Not with pure TS, no. TypeScript's type system is erased when you compile your program. There's nothing at runtime left of PickingItemWithArticle. If you want something to happen at runtime you need to add runtime code. This really feels like an XY problem, since you're worried about dynamically removing any possible future extra things instead of just providing the known required things. I'm not sure how to proceed here. Please [edit] to clarify.
